# Sum the numbers in a string in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Below is the interview question, can some please help me resolve it?

```
select 'a1b2c3d4e5f6g7' from dual;
```

Output is sum of given integer number(1+2+3+4+5+6+7)=28.
Any help?

Answer (score 10):

Use a Regex to keep only the numbers,then connect by to add each number

```
With T
as (select regexp_replace('a1b2c3d4e5f6g7', '[A-Za-z]') as col from dual)
select sum(val)
From
(
select substr(col,level,1) val from t connect by level <= length(col)
)
```

[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7db59d16c/3555)

Comment: Nice! I was fiddling with something down the same lines, but your solution is much more elegant. I need to start getting used to using CTEs.

Answer (score 5):

Since it is only 1 digit numbers you can use `SUBSTR()` to extract every other character:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7db59d16c/3571)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

**Query 1**:

```
WITH data ( value ) AS (
  select 'a1b2c3d4e5f6g7' from dual
)
SELECT SUM( TO_NUMBER( SUBSTR( value, 2*LEVEL, 1 ) ) ) AS total
FROM   data
CONNECT BY 2 * LEVEL <= LENGTH( value )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7db59d16c/3571/0)**:

```
| TOTAL |
|-------|
|    28 |
```

However, if you have two digit numbers then you can do:

**Query 2**:

```
WITH data ( value ) AS (
  select 'a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8i9j10' from dual
)
SELECT SUM( TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '\d+', 1, LEVEL ) ) ) AS total
FROM   data
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT( value, '\d+' )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7db59d16c/3571/1)**:

```
| TOTAL |
|-------|
|    55 |
```

Comment: It seems SO no more notifies when someone else posted an answer while I am writing one.

Answer (score 2):

You can use regexp_substr to extract exactly the numbers, then just sum them:

```
with t as (select 'a1b2c3d4e5f6g7' expr from dual)
select sum(regexp_substr(t.expr, '[0-9]+',1, level)) as col
from dual
connect by level < regexp_instr(t.expr, '[0-9]+',1, level);
```

example:

```
select sum(regexp_substr('a1b2c3d4e5f6g7r22g4', '[0-9]+',1, level)) as col
from dual
connect by level < regexp_instr('a1b2c3d4e5f6g7r22g4', '[0-9]+',1, level);
```

Result:
54

Answer (score 2):

This solution works with numbers with more than 1 digit and it doesn't matter how many characters are between the numbers:

```
with t as (select 'a1b2c3d4e5f6g7' as str from dual)
  select sum(to_number(regexp_substr(str,'[0-9]+',1,level)))
  from t
  connect by regexp_substr(str,'[0-9]+',1,level) is not null
```

Answer (score -1):

I used the solution of summing elements in a record cell, but I still needed to add up the resulting totals per month. I haven't found such a solution anywhere, so I'm presenting my solution - maybe it will be helpful to someone.

[My table: AWARIE_SIECIOWE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGvxl.png)
Solution:

```
select t.mies,
    sum((select sum(to_number(regexp_substr(t.impact,'[0-9]+',1,level))) from dual
     connect by regexp_substr(t.impact,'[0-9]+',1,level) is not null)) as result
    from AWARIE_SIECIOWE t
    where t.mies >= '2021-01' and t.mies < '2024-01'
    group by t.mies
    order by t.mies asc
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation to this answer.

Comment: [Edit] your answer and add the explanation. Don't post answer details in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32601988/sum-the-numbers-in-a-string-in-oracle/78156800#comment137815263_78156800).